# EF4 Performance using IN instead of JOIN

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Is there any performance issue to be aware about using this sql statement generated by EF

C# code:

```
 public IQueryable<Lugar> NearestPOI(double lat, double lng, int> distance)
            {
                System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Int32?> AllowedPois = dbContext.SP_NearestPOI(lat, lng, 100000);


                IQueryable<Lugar> POI = from c in dbContext.Lugars
                          where AllowedPois.Contains(c.id)
                          select c;

                return POI;
            }
```

EF4 Generated query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[empresaId] AS [empresaId], 
[Extent1].[usuarioId] AS [usuarioId], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[lat] AS [lat], 
[Extent1].[lng] AS [lng],
[Extent1].[logoThumbnail] AS [logoThumbnail], 
[Extent1].[imageType] AS [imageType]
FROM [dbo].[Lugares] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[id] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

My concern is about doing the AllowedPois query as a separate one instaed of using the regular approach on pure SQL syntax that would be something like:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Lugares  L join dbo.NearestPOI(9.105306627167566,-79.38148587942118,100000) NL
on L.id = NL.id
```

As im using EF4 for this project I would like to stick with it and do not use string concatenation for the querys. I tried to generate a more compelling query using this approach:

```
var POI = from c in dbContext.Lugars
          join i in dbContext.SP_NearestPOI(lat, lng, 100000) on c.id  equals i.Value
          select c;
```

But it give out a really messy query with N number of unions that increments with the number of allowedPois:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[empresaId] AS [empresaId], 
[Extent1].[usuarioId] AS [usuarioId], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[lat] AS [lat], 
[Extent1].[lng] AS [lng], 
[Extent1].[logoThumbnail] AS [logoThumbnail], 
[Extent1].[imageType] AS [imageType]
FROM  [dbo].[Lugares] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll5].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll4].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM  (SELECT 
                [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1]
                FROM  (SELECT 
                    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1]
                    FROM  (SELECT 
                        1 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT 
                        2 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                    3 AS [C1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]) AS [UnionAll2]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                4 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]) AS [UnionAll3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            5 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]) AS [UnionAll4]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        6 AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable6]) AS [UnionAll5]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    7 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable7]) AS [UnionAll6] ON [Extent1].[id] = [UnionAll6].[C1]
```

Any idea on how to improve this operation or should I stick with my actual solution using the separate query for the allowedPois?

Comment: I hate var, what exactly your nearestpoi returns? And what is wrong with IN? Instead it will be better to use your SP in where expression somehow.

Comment: =D, updated question with explicit types, SP_NearestPOI return a list of INT (the ids of the records that comply with the radius requirement). That is what im trying to archive but the resulting SQL from my TRY is not what I expected

Comment: Is SP_NearestPOI a stored procedure? If so, you can't join on the result of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't use the join syntax in a LINQ query. Part of me wishes they didn't include the join operator in the C# language for LINQ because it just leads to confusion and tends to generate bad SQL like this. The reason being is that you almost are always joining in SQL to when you want to do a where clause or include that table in your results. LINQ already has great support for this but you just have to think in the LINQ way and not the SQL way. Your LINQ data model should have the relationships defined so you don't then need to redefine them through joins. Doesn't totally apply here since you're using a sproc first but same principles apply. Your first LINQ query in C# is actually the efficient way to do it.

So, in case I wasn't clear. This is the right code.

```
public IQueryable<Lugar> NearestPOI(double lat, double lng, int> distance)
            {
                System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Int32?> AllowedPois = dbContext.SP_NearestPOI(lat, lng, 100000);


                IQueryable<Lugar> POI = from c in dbContext.Lugars
                          where AllowedPois.Contains(c.id)
                          select c;

                return POI;
            }
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion, at the end I created a Store Procedure to handle this because i also needed to do pagination and filtering, and it works fine.

Comment: If you want pagination that is even easier in LINQ than in SQL. Just do var x = POI.Skip(20).Take(10) where "Skip" is skipping the first 20 items and "Take" is taking 20. So this would be looking at the third page of items for instance.